# jQuery Sub menu don't close when hover on other sub menu item

Tags: jquery, html, css

My menu works on hover event, when I hover on sub menu, it opens its own child menu, but when I hover on other sub menu, the previous sub menu's child should close itself. Please check my working jsfiddle :

http://jsfiddle.net/samia/3N7BG/

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
$(".topmenu .sub-menu .parent a").mouseover(function() {
        if($(this).parent().attr('id') != $("li .open").attr('id') 
            && $(this).parent().has("ul").length > 0) {
            if($("li .open").length > 0) {
                $("li .open").children("ul").slideToggle(1000);
                $("li .open").toggleClass("open");
            }
            $(this).parent().children("ul").slideToggle(200);
            $(this).parent().toggleClass("open");
        }
});
```

Do remember that in this approach if the menu slidingUp (e.g., Design) is considerably longer than the menu slidingDown (e.g., Development) then you will run into a situation where 'Development' might slideUp because the mouse will leave it's covered area due to the slidingUp of 'Design'. Just add another item to the 'Design' menu to test this.

For the current list of items the above implementation should work fine.